# Calculating 100 Miles Within a Radius

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Given I have a table that contains a list of airports with their associated lat and long coordinates, how would I go about getting a list of airports that are within 100 miles of another coordinate? My end-goal is to have a user search by city and find airports within 100 miles of that's city's latitude and longitude. I have all the data just don't know where to begin.

My data is in SQL Server.

Comment: How many miles are between a latitudes and longitudes?  That's what you need to find out

Comment: What version of SQL-Server are you using? If you have SQL Server 2008, you can use GeoCoordinates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862856/storing-and-querying-gps-coordinates-effectively contains some good info too.

Comment: I answered a very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628794/radius-search-by-latitude-longitude/15640498#15640498. Requires SQL 2008 or higher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create function dbo.F_GREAT_CIRCLE_DISTANCE
(
    @Latitude1  float,
    @Longitude1 float,
    @Latitude2  float,
    @Longitude2 float
)
returns float as
begin
    declare @radius float

    declare @lon1  float
    declare @lon2  float
    declare @lat1  float
    declare @lat2  float

    declare @a float
    declare @distance float

    -- Sets average radius of Earth in Miles
    set @radius = 3956

    -- Convert degrees to radians
    set @lon1 = radians( @Longitude1 )
    set @lon2 = radians( @Longitude2 )
    set @lat1 = radians( @Latitude1 )
    set @lat2 = radians( @Latitude2 )

    set @a = sqrt(square(sin((@lat2-@lat1)/2.0E)) + (cos(@lat1) * cos(@lat2) * square(sin((@lon2-@lon1)/2.0E))) )
    set @distance = @radius * ( 2.0E *asin(case when 1.0E < @a then 1.0E else @a end ))

    return @distance
end
```

Comment: @Markus is the result in Miles?

Comment: @LoneWOLFs Yes it is, change the radius to 6366.7 if you want it in km.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate` class

```
GeoCoordinate city = ....;
double distance = .......;
List<GeoCoordinate> airports = .......; //load from db.

var found = airports.Where(c=>c.GetDistanceTo(city) < distance);
```

**EDIT**

For those who might be interested in a real working code

```
var airports1 = Airports.Search(51, 0, 100).ToList(); //~London
var airports2 = Airports.Search(40.714623, -74.006605,100).ToList(); //~NY
```

---

```
public class Airports
{
    public class Airport
    {
        public string Name;
        public GeoCoordinate Location;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    static Lazy<List<Airport>> _Airports = new Lazy<List<Airport>>(() =>
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var json = wc.DownloadString("http://www.flightradar24.com/AirportDataService2.php");
                var jObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string[]>>(json);

                return jObj.Values
                           .Select(j => new Airport
                            {
                                Name = (string)j[2],
                                Location = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(j[3].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(j[4].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                            })
                            .ToList();
            }
        }, true);

    public static IEnumerable<Airport> Search(double lat,double lon, double distInMiles)
    {
        var loc = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);
        return _Airports.Value.Where(c => c.Location.GetDistanceTo(loc) < distInMiles * 1609.344);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP is asking for a solution in T-SQL.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 That may be so, but its been tagged with C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
 --SELECT Points closer than @radius
select * from #Points p
WHERE power(p.x - @locX, 2) + POWER(p.y - @locY, 2) < POWER(@radius,2)
```

(this has been shamelessly ripped from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1228111-8-1.aspx#bm1229043, found via Google Search for SQL + Pyhtagoras).

Comment: Unfortunately, the distance between two longitude lines differs by latitude, so this solution simply does not work in practice.

Comment: Also, don't forget that distances on the surface of the earth measure the distance *as the earth curves*, not the distance *straight through the earth* between two points. It's a lot faster to get to China if you go direct, but digging that tunnel will be some piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

in case if you have your airport at point 0,0,
all airports within 30 mile radius should be inside a circle.
to test if point is inside a circle, you need to test each square equation:
sqrt(X*X + Y*Y) < R,
where X, Y - location of each sity, R = 100 miles

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula for 'as the crow flies distances between two points:
Haversine

```
formula:     a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos(φ1).cos(φ2).sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
```

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
    note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!

You could translate this code into SQL

```
JavaScript: 
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```

Here is a link to the T-SQL page for mathematical functions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188919.aspx